OMNet++ 6.03 INET 4.5 how to run INET showcases?
I installed OMNet++ 6.03 and INET 4.5 on Windows 11. While I can simulate INET examples without any issues, I'm having trouble running the showcases.
When I double-click on the omnetpp.ini file, it reports that it cannot find the network to simulate. Unlike the INET examples, I don't see any NED files in the showcases. Does anyone have an idea on how to run an INET showcase simulation? What mistake might I be making? How to get NED files for INET showcases?

First make sure INET version is compatible with omnet++, did your inet build successfully, if Yes then you can able to run any showcase in inet by right click on .ini file, showcases are pre built small simulations that you can use in your projects.
If you still face error, we can meet to trouble out this error.
